# Dropbox API nuget installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dropbox-api

I'm trying to install the dropbox api.  The first time I tried it, it told me my project was at 4.5.2 so it wouldn't install.

I then discovered that the latest dropbox api (6.8.0) required .net 4.6.1.  So I changed my project to use that framework, and I still get an error when I attempt to install it.  I then changed to framework 4.7.2 and it still failed:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Dropbox.Api 6.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Anyone have any ideas what to do?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

The [minimum requirement to use .net standard libs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-standard-libraries-and-visual-studio) is to use Visual Studio 2015 with the update 3 + a [special hotfix](https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx), but it is better to use VS2017 or 2019:

> If you only need to consume .NET Standard 2.0 libraries in your
> projects, you can also do that in Visual Studio 2015. However, you
> need [NuGet client 3.6 or higher installed](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

So make sure the hotfix + latest nuget client is installed.